# Make an empty container the same size as a different container with a child image using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Incorrect size:** Here's what it looks like on load:

[image]

**Correct size:** Here's what it looks like on window resize:

[image]

**PROJECT LINK** Here is a reference link: https://wp.xingapps.win/

**Instructions:** Hover over "Shop Ejuice" black button in top navigation and you will see red boxes. These red boxes should match the height of the first image but arent.

**Story:** I have a problem where im trying to reduce the amount of image requests on a page. I have a grid of images. Instead of loading all the images which are all the same height and width I am just going to load the first image and than the other images will be a `<div>` that matches the first images height and width. I will then apply a CSS Sprite background images to these `div`'s so they appear as normal images. This will reduce the amount of requests on the page by a lot!

**Issue:** My example code is working when i resize the browser - it will match the height of the source image perfectly. However on initial load the height and width are incorrect. For some reason a bit smaller than it should be. Not fixed until i resize the window. How do i fix this?

**The code:**

```
(function($){
/* Match Quad Menu Div Height to one image */
var imgContainer = $('.mad-hat-parent-menu .quadmenu-product-float'),
    sourceImg = $('li#menu-item-15959 span.quadmenu-item-content');

function resizeDiv () {
    imgContainer.height(sourceImg.width());
    imgContainer.width(sourceImg.width());
}

$(window).on("load resize", function() { resizeDiv(); });

})(jQuery);
```

**Note:** (i am actually targetting the container of the first image instead of the image itself)
 Additionally **this issue is hard to see if you are on a screen width smaller than 1650px**.

Comment: It is probably calculating before the page has finished rendering, i.e. before the images have loaded in. You need to fire an event after the page has actually rendered fully with your rejiggling as a callback

Comment: yeah "on load" should of covered that tho.. Also its the last thing loaded in the dom already (the script)

Comment: No, on load is just that. The page itself as a document but it relies on assets not part of the page. What you are seeing is effectively a text file, interpreted as images, stylings, etc, etc from parsers in browser. The page has loaded as a text document (HTML is a text document) does not necessarily mean the 500 HTTP requests you'll be making for the images, fonts, CSS, JS, etc, etc. will be at that time. For a cheap, really shitty hack, `setTimeout(() => { // resizing in here }, 0)` should do it.

Comment: If i set the timeout to any number between 0 - 500 the code works but doesnt solve my problem. If i set the timeout to like 600+ it doesnt work at all.

Comment: Hi guys! I made a JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nLv0xt52/1/embedded/result/

Which has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Try to use the resizeDiv() when the user opens/hovers/clicks the menu, like:

Like:

```js
$(".quadmenu-dropdown-toggle").on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
      resizeDiv();
    },
    click: function(){
      resizeDiv();
    }
});
```

Comment: Or use the 'wrong way' with setTimeout as @ggdx mentioned

Comment: Both ggdx's timeout suggestion and this answer are not working for me unfortunately.

Comment: That's a brilliant approach. It still doesnt work however. There must be something else wrong =/ its grabbing a size tho its just wrong one. Confusing.

Comment: I made a JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nLv0xt52/1/embedded/result/

Which has the same problem.

Comment: It seems to work in your fiddle, not?
The only think that's breaking is the multiline text in my screen